# What does $t_0$ mean in constant acceleration equations?

Tags: kinematics, time, terminology, coordinate-systems, notation

I am using the book Understanding Physics by Mansfield and O'Sullivan. In their derivation of constant acceleration equations, they initially use a time $t_0$ that is not necessarily $0$. They get $v=v(t_0)+a(t-t_0)$ and a similar equation for $x$ (ie one involving $t_0$).

However, I am confused as to what $t_0$ means. According to the authors, $x(t_0)$, $v(t_0)$ and $t_0$ are "starting conditions". They also call $t_0$ the "starting instant".

But what do "starting" and "initial" mean here? As far as I know, we do not need them to be "starting" at all: all that we need is an arbitrary time for which we know $v(t_0)$ and $x(t_0)$. In other words, $t_0$ doesn't need to be initial, it just has to be a random time for which we know $v(t_0)$ and $x(t_0)$, then we can use it to find the constants of integration (by setting $t=t_0$), resulting in the equations above involving $t_0$.

Also, I am still wondering what "starting" in itself actually means: did they start measuring from that time? But measuring what? As I said, we don't need to measure anything: the constant acceleration equations result purely mathematically from the definition of acceleration, ie $a=\frac{dv}{dt}$, and the only thing we need to know to find the constants of integration is the velocity and position for an arbitrary value $t_0$. So what does $t_0$ being an "initial" or "starting" value have anything to do with it? If anything, it only has to be "known".

Edit: It is not the same as the suggested question. That one is whether $t_0$ can be nonzero (the answer is yes), this one on the other hand is about why we call $t_0$ the "initial" or "starting" time, when it is just an arbitrary time for which we happen to know x and v.

Comment: You seem to understand the Physics, and I wonder if you're being just a trifle pedantic. Can we not interpret 'starting time' simply as the start of the interval $(t-t_0)$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the initial time be non-zero?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377521/) posted by the same user.

Comment: @PhilipWood: I feel these are important things to get right, I was told to ask stupid questions. Please read my answer, it doesn't seem too simple after I thought about it, it involves the difference between mathematical formalism and physical intuition. Please read my answer to see

Comment: @PhilipWood: Please read my answer, I would appreciate feedback on whether it is a correct.

Comment: $t_0$ is just the beginning of the range you choose to look at. The time when you start looking / measuring / caring. That is all. If you want to calculate the path of a flower pot as it falls between the third and second window, then $t_0$ is the time at the third.

Comment: Agree about the advice to ask stupid questions (though 'simplistic' might be better than 'stupid'). But I'd also say that, if you're learning Physics, you need to know when to let go of intractable difficulties, promising yourself to come back to them when you have time. I've commented on your answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In constant acceleration equations, we really care about how much a body has moved over time (i.e. change in position), not "absolute position" (this isn't actually a real thing because it is completely relative to whatever coordinate system you choose).

The fact that we care about $\Delta x$ (change in position) rather than some $x$ relative to a coordinate system means that we should likewise care about $\Delta t$ (change in time), not some "absolute time" (which certainly isn't a well defined concept).

Why, then, does $(t-t_0)$ come into play? Sure, you can usually take $t_0 = 0$ because it doesn't change the mathematics, but a lot of these things are based on physical interpretation. Suppose you're running an experiment and you have a stopwatch, and the experiment occurs between $t=3$ and $t=5$ on your stopwatch. When you do your kinematics calculations, you will end up doing the subtraction $5-3$—that is, $(t-t_0)$—to get the right answer.

This may seem a little artificial, but the expression $(t-t_0)$ is the only way you can capture the kinematics in full generality. The concept of "initial time" and "final time" is just "What time interval do we care about in this experiment?"

Answer (score -1):

I think I have solved the problem after thinking about it.

Basically, I forgot the mathematical formalism for a moment and thought about it physically. We want to know the general velocity and position of a body that is moving at constant acceleration. Therefore, all we need is one moment in time for which we know the position and velocity, then we can use the constant acceleration to get other times. In other words, we know $v(t_0)$, so we just do $v(t_0)+at$ for times more than $t_0$, and $v(t_0)-at$ for times less than $t_0$. This is without using any "mathematics", since we know that each second, the velocity increases by $a$ since it is constant acceleration.

Now let's see how this compares with the integral formalism. As it turns out, $t_0$ is not an initial time at all, it is only an arbitrary time, as it clear from the intuitive physical explanation above. It is only when we come to the mathematics that it all of a sudden becomes an "initial" time. Do you know why? Because in the mathematical formalism, when we work out the area under the a-t graph, we have to choose an "initial" time on the graph from which we work out the area. It couldn't be otherwise, since area is 2-D and we have to start somewhere, ie $\int_{t_0}^t$. If there was some magical mathematical way we could avoid starting somewhere, and invent a notation where we don't appear to "start" at $t_0$, say $\zeta(t_0)$ (this isn't like $\int_{t_0}^t$ which has the illusion of "starting" at $t_0$ and moving to $t$), then it would be as clear as the physical explanation above. (However, I guess we can rest contented with the fact that $\int_{t_0}^t = -\int _t^{t_0}$, so that it does have symmetry after all, and does not have to have an illusion of starting at $t_0$). Unfortunately, this is not the case. So the mathematical formalism makes it look like $t_0$ is an "initial" time. It is not: it is simply an arbitrary time for which we know v and x.

So it isn't as simple as I thought at first. The fact that authors call it "initial" and "starting" time is due to the mathematics, in particular, how it appears on the graph. It has nothing to do with the physics.

Comment: You are over-thinking this *and* assigning your own pre-conceived idea of the what the word "initial" means.  In the sense used here, "initial" means "at the initial moment of consideration, at which time we know the state of the object".  You said this yourself in your original question.  *Many* words used in physics have meanings different from their use in real life.  Classic examples are *work* and *heat*.  Every field uses words in specific ways.  You will find this to a shocking degree when you write your first patent.

Comment: @garyp Thanks, I do seem to have over analysed now that I've slept on it. At least I am not so entrenched in my "pre-conceived ideas" as to not be willing to admit this. I should probably also learn not to be so sceptical when reading books by PhD's in the field and rather question my own understanding a bit more :-)

Comment: You make the good point that $t$ could be less than $t_0$, yet the constant acceleration equations will still work. Calling $t_0$ the 'starting time' relies on the convention that $t>t_0$ unless stated otherwise. [Incidentally, I'd prefer to state the equations as $v=u+a \Delta t$ and so on.]

Comment: @PhilipWood Thanks, yeah it is a convention after all, since no one is telling us to go to the right when working out the area under a-t. Makes sense now.

Answer (score -2):

$t_0$ is called starting because it might as well have been the beginning of our imaginary universe. What happened before it is entirely irrelevant - maybe nothing happened before it and this is indeed the very beginning of the existence of the universe we are examining. Maybe we're dealing with the aftermath from when the Martian invaders were repelled by chimpanzee reinforcements from the Yukon. Or maybe this is the universe where you don't click 'Continue Watching' when Netflix barks at you and you go to bed like a reasonable adult. (This never happens, but it could, in theory.)

But none of that matters. $t_0$ is the beginning of any *interesting* activity. No matter what happened before $t_0$ we will always have the exact same starting conditions. And because the universe is pretty darned reliable, we know that the exact same starting conditions for any scenario will produce the same results. (If you got a different result, then clearly some starting condition was different. No lectures about cats in boxes, please.)

Everything noteworthy will happen at some point after $t_0$. That's why it's called the starting instant. If there was something that mattered *before* $t_0$, well, then the time that that thing happened is now $t_0$.

Comment: Very curious as to why this might have received downvotes. I'm struggling to find anything in it that is incorrect and does not answer the question.